# Do you need to use jQuery.when with a single deferred object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Say you have the following piece of code:

```
function someProcess() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    apiCall(function (recvData) {
        deferred.resolveWith(null, [recvData]);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}

function mainFunction() {
    $.when(someProcess())
        .then(someOtherProcess);
}
```

In this example I only need to wait for a single deferred to be resolved. In this case, what is the difference (if any) between writing the second function as above versus writing it like this:

```
function mainFunction() {
    someProcess()
        .then(someOtherProcess);
}
```

I mean, I like writing it the first way because it makes it clear that we're using jQuery deferred objects, but I'm curious if it's necessary in this case.

edit: I fixed a typo in the then() call. Thanks for catching that.

edit: Thanks for the answer nrabinowitz. I think you have nailed the points that I was not sure about in regard to using when() vs. using a raw jQuery deferred object instance. I went and fixed my code again to return a promise instead of the entire deferred object. That is how I do it in my actual code right now, just forgot to add it here.

Comment: `someOtherProcess()` should be `someOtherProcess`. In the first case, you're immediately calling the function.

Comment: @RobW I think he should be calling it immediately, as `$.when` expects the deferred object returned by the function, not a function.

Comment: @KevinB `someOtherProcess()` is inside `then`, not `when`.

Comment: You are right. I have fixed that mistake. Only the when() function takes a deferred as its parameter, the other methods take a function as the input parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used custom Deferred objects, but my understanding is that there are two differences in your examples:

- Using `$.when()` allows you to arbitrarily add more deferred objects to be handled by your handlers. Obviously, not a big deal, since you'd have to change that line of code either way to add more deferreds.
- `$.when()` only gets the Promise object, not the whole deferred object, which if I understand correctly is a consistency measure to hide the deferred's state-changing methods (e.g. `resolve()`), only exposing handler hooks and state inspection methods. This seems like good practice, but in your example you could do the same thing by calling `someProcess().promise()` instead of `$.when(someProcess())`.

So I think you're right - both methods will work, but the main benefit of using `$.when()` is to make the code more legible and set expectations appropriately for other programmers. Using either `$.when()` or `deferred.promise()` will additionally help protect against some less competent coder messing with the state of your deferred in a confusing way.

Comment: Thanks. I pretty much agree with everything you've stated so I'm going to go ahead and let this question be resolved. I appreciate the input.